# How to draw an arrow with a border?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, system.drawing

I am attempting to draw an arrow which has a border or a outline. I am drawing this arrow as an overlay within a third-party program.  Here is a simplified example of that code.

```
private void DrawWindArrow(Graphics Screen, int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Entering...DrawWindArrow");
            NArrow.FontSize = 10;
            NArrow.CenterText = 20;
            NArrow.Scale = GetScale(NArrow.Size);
            NArrow.Scale += 0.2f;
            NArrow.CalculateArrowSize(NArrow.Scale);
            NArrow.FontSize = ChangeFontSize(NArrow.Size);
            NArrow.CoordinateX = GetXCoordinates(NArrow.Position, screenWidth);
            NArrow.CoordinateY = GetYCoordinates(NArrow.Position, screenHeight);
            NArrow.CenterText = CenterText(NArrow.Size, NArrow.CoordinateX);
            NArrow.CalculateArrowProperties();
            NArrow.CenterOfArrowy = NArrow.CenterOfArrow + NArrow.CoordinateY;
            NArrow.CenterOfArrow += NArrow.CoordinateX;  
        }    
    }
```

Here is an example of the arrow I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Geez, I'm thankful WPF exists now that I look at this.

Comment: quick side question, what's the point of making your members private if you have public getters and setters for all of them?

Comment: @BenJones - I already actually solved this problem awhile ago.  I was just trying to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day I ended up redesigning and refactoring the orignal code in its entirely.  What I ended up doing was drawing a smaller arrow based on a ratio of the original arrow.

In the end I was able to figure out, there wasn't a single thing I did, I simply used a different approach.